# Java BigDecimal.toPlainString() performance

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Java `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` becomes hot spot of my app. Is there a faster way to get plain string of `BigDecimal`?

Comment: if you're using Java **and** worry about performance ... well ... you're doing it wrong. Java wasnt built for performance - at all. If you want maximum performance you need languages like C or even ASM, its that easy. Instead of trying to re-invent the wheel you should simply put your method call into a thread and display its progress

Comment: @specializt huh - right...

Comment: yeah ... sorry to burst your bubble.

Comment: @specializt "*Java was not built for performance - at all*" was probably true in 2000...

Comment: it still is, of course.

Comment: @specializt: well, I suppose that all those folks that developed performance-critical solutions on all those enterprise back-ends where Java predominates should have talked to you first, then, eh?

Comment: Its easy to simulate "performance" with multithreading and clever UI design or even well-planned software architectures in general but that wont change the fact that it never was, isnt and never will be possible to achieve machine-code performance with bytecode. Thats a mathematical fact, no matter how much you seem to love your new language.

Comment: @specializt: That's nonsense. It is not easy to simulate performance at all. And current JIT compilers produce machine code, they don't interpret bytecode anymore (that was ages ago, but not anymore). So it is very well possible that languages like Java or C# equal or even outdo "native" languages like C++ or C. Note that compilers like Clang also produce bytecode, which is later compiled to the given platform.

Comment: you're obviously disconnected from reality. The java compiler produces bytecode which needs to be COMPILED before it can be run - hence it will  always be slower than any precompiled machinecode. You're actually trying to disprove math itself. Nice try though - and now back to your programming exercises, please because this is getting quite shameful for you ... just saying

Comment: Java is performant enough for most situations, but arbitrary precision arithmetic, such as provided by `BigDecimal`, is known to be much slower than equivalent libraries available in C, such as `Gnu MP`.  However, Java still competes, because you can easily wrap C libraries in native calls using Java Native Access (JNA).  In fact this is already done for you.  Here is the maven artifact to include `Gnu MP` in your Java application: `com.squareup.jnagmp:jnagmp`

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` method can be an option.

But just ran a test on it , toPlainString() was the clear winner.

From Oracle Docs:

> String    toPlainString() Returns a string representation of this
>   BigDecimal without an exponent field.
>
> String toString() Returns the
>   string representation of this BigDecimal, using scientific notation if
>   an exponent is needed.